# preg_replace ".php"?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

How do I preg_replace .php from end of string?

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($sidebar_links); $x++) {

   $sidebar[$x] = $x;           
}
```

$sidebar_links:

```
array(3) { [0]=>  string(9) "index.php" [1]=>  string(9) "site2.php" [2]=>  string(7) "site3.php" }
```

Comment: you can use simple str_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use simple [str_replace](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

like

```
str_replace('.php', '', $sidebar_links[$x]);
```

or [basename](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
basename($sidebar_links[$x], ".php");
```

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace('\.php$', '', $sidebar_link)`

Or, to avoid regex:

```
if (substr($sidebar_link, -4) == ".php")
     $sidebar_link = substr($sidebar_link, 0, -4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code for replacing file extension. Instead of replacing just unset last index of array.

```
private function changeFileExtension($imagePath, $ext=""){
        $arr = explode(".", $imagePath);
        if(count($arr) > 0)
        {
            $arr[count($arr)-1] = $ext;
            return implode(".", $arr);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```